# Is php.ini upload_max_filesize combined?

Tags: php, file-upload

Is `upload_max_filesize` for one single file or for multiple files?

For example, if the property is set to `upload_max_filesize: 5M`, is it possible to upload three single files which are 2 MB each (for a total of 6MB)? Or will that not work because `upload_max_filesize` is set to 5MB?

I've been doing some tests but I would like to know the community's perspective.

Comment: what were the test results?

Comment: The upload_max_filesize is based per each post request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `post_max_size` to set the total and `upload_max_filesize` for max per file.

Check: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

- `upload_max_filesize` `int` - The maximum size of an uploaded file. When an int is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described in [this FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes), may also be used.

And https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

- `post_max_size` `int` - Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than `upload_max_filesize`. Generally speaking, [`memory_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) should be larger than `post_max_size`. When an int is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described in [this FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes), may also be used. If the size of post data is greater than `post_max_size`, the `$_POST` and `$_FILES` superglobals are empty. This can be tracked in various ways, e.g. by passing the `$_GET` variable to the script processing the data, i.e. `<form action="edit.php?processed=1">`, and then checking if `$_GET['processed']` is set.

Comment: Are you sure that upload_max_filesize is per file, rather than total size of all files uploaded as indicated by @l'L'l?

Comment: The quoted doc still doesn't make it cristal clear for me whether `upload_max_filesize` is for one file or combined.

Comment: @Benjamin, the docs say `upload_max_filesize` is "The maximum size of *an uploaded file*" not "*all uploaded files*" so yes, it is *per file* not total.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that **`upload_max_filesize` is the maximum size per file**.

e.g. with `upload_max_filesize=2M`, you can upload 3 files of `1.5M`.

I just confirmed this by testing.

---

### Limits you should care about:

- `upload_max_filesize` (default `2M`): max size **per individual file**;
- `max_file_uploads` (default `20`): max number of files you can send **per request**;
- `post_max_size` (default `8M`): max **raw** POST data size **per request**;
  `post_max_size` must be greater than the sum of the sizes of:

  - all uploaded files
  - all data in other POST fields
  - a few extra KB to account for the `multipart/form-data` overhead (headers/boundaries) that wrap every single file and every single POST field in the payload.

Be really careful with these limits, as PHP **will not error** if you exceed one of them; instead, you'll end up with partial or empty `$_POST` or `$_FILES` and might have a hard time debugging the issue.

For example, `max_file_uploads` will silently ignore any file past the `n`<sup>th</sup> uploaded file, and you'll end up with a truncated list of files with no warning whatsoever.